# VB.NET Active Directory vs Database security

Tags: database, vb.net, security, active-directory

I would like to add security to my application.
I found impractical to store user names, passwords and groups in the database.

Instead, I want to use Active Directory for user authentication.

Let me explain:

Let's say I want to use 3 Active Directory groups: MyAppUsers, MyAppEngineers and MyAppAdmins.

When user types in his name and password the application checks them against Active Directory, if user exist then I want application to check which user group this user belongs to? I'm stuck here.

I don't want to hard code group names in the application like this:

- If "johnsmith" is in the list of "MyAppEngineers" then activate
  Engineer's screen
- If "johnsmith" is in the list of "MyAppAdmins" then activate Admin's
  screen

Is it possible to to this without database table where the relation between 
"application groups" and "AD groups" is stored????

I came up with only one solution:

Create a database table where I will relate "application groups" with "AD groups"

Database table:

- AppLevel1=MyAppUsers
- AppLevel2=MyAppEngineers
- AppLevel3=MyAppAdmins

and then use these generic groups in the application

- If "johnsmith" is in the list of "AppLeve2" then activate Engineer's
  screen
- If "johnsmith" is in the list of "AppLeve3" then activate Admin's
  screen

But the issue in if AD group name is changed the database table needs to be updated accordingly.

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: What database? If it's SQL Server it has AD Security built into it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry, but I think you missed the point, I don't want to use DB at all. The main question is "Is it possible to do this without database where the relation between "application groups" and "AD groups" is stored and use just AD?"